# Is the "at" symbol @ relatively safe in file paths?

Tags: files, osx, posix

I am thinking about a naming convention for files and folders in an open source library - paths with these 4 names have a special meaning:

```
@src
@target
@transform.sh
@run.sh
```

Besides tab completion being a bit wonky, everything seems to be fine - does anyone foresee a problem with using the at symbol in file paths?

Is there another good symbol I can use to create a unique identifier in a path?

Maybe the < > characters would be safer than @...

Comment: How about using `_` ?

Comment: Underscores would work but aren't "cool" lol

Comment: If you need cool (and your filesystem could use UNICODE, which I believe Macs could), use ☺, or some other cool unicode character.

Comment: Good luck typing your file paths without tab completion @Arrow ! ^_^

Comment: Ha yeah, but if you put \@ (escaping the @) then you can get tab completion, still is a bit wonky sometimes. I was thinking of using < > instead of @...the point is I need something that won't have a namespace conflict with another directory in someone's project.

Comment: Turns out the < > characters also need escaping, just like @...hmm

Comment: two words: don't! I cannot see the benefit of using special characters in file paths, they will only create issues later. Use a prefix instead!

I think convenience beats cool, anytime!

Comment: well I am looking to create unique directory names, that are very unlikely to clash with existing names in a user's directory. It's ok if they clash, the user can change the name with some configuration. But the default directory name should be very unlikely to clash. The only thing I can think of is special chars. See my answer.

Comment: I have come across many issues with weird characters in file/folder paths, seriously, use a prefix instead. Besides, why is a leading underscore not cool ?

"An initial underscore already conveys strong feelings of magicalness to a C programmer." Larry Wall

Comment: Check out what this guy says, what do ya'll think - https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-easily-generate-unicode-characters-with-one-keystroke-on-Linux/answer/Sam-Tanai

Answer (score 4):

The @ symbol is usually understood as the start of a hostname.

```
mail bob@example.net
```

That is a sign that many programs that may use the network may get confused by such a character. Probably prepending an slash `/@` may reduce such confusions but why fight the system if starting files with `_` has no network use and seems more robust.

If what you need is "cool" and your filesystem could use unicode (some filesystems can not), then use:

```
☺src
☺target
☺transform.sh
☺run.sh
```

Or cool: `❄src`  with rythm: `♫src` or `ʕ•ᴥ•ʔsrc`, take your pick.

Yes, there are many 'one character' symbols, take a look at [the emoji block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block))

---

#### Paste the emoji

There are several ways to "type" the emoji but all require a "paste" to be used for `completion`.

1. Copy and paste from a web page that has the emoji you need.
2. Place the emojis you need in a file and:

   ```
   $ cat emojifile
   ☺       ❄       ♫       ʕ•ᴥ•ʔ
   ```

   Then: copy and paste.
3. Remember the emoji code point and print it:

   ```
   $ printf '\U263A\n'
   ☺
   ```

   Then: copy and paste.
4. Improve the emoji file by appending the Unicode codepoint to the emoji:
   A emoji number could be found by:

   ```
   $ printf '%X' '"☺'
   263A

   $ cat emojifile
   ☺ \U263A        ❄ \U2744        ♫ \U266B        ʕ•ᴥ•ʔ \U295\U2022\U1D25\U2022\U294       \U1F913
   ```

Comment: +1 for suggesting emojis. It will certainly cause problems somewhere down the road, but the fun is worth it...

Comment: Yeah emojis will be a nice ticking timebomb lol

Comment: I think my users would run far away without tab completion. If someone could find me unicode character emoji that works with tab completion, I will write you a personal check for $100 lol

Comment: @AlexanderMills Tab completion does work for me here with a `☺target` file. When I have a file named as such, a `☺` and type a `tab` it does complete, but this is not an OSx. Just try if you want, if you don't like what you see, don't use it. OSx will get better in the future (I hope).

Comment: It seems to work on OSX sierra, so that's cool

Comment: sure you can get tab completion but how do you type the emoji? :) you have to copy/paste it. Unless there is some fancy keyboard shortcut for emojis

Comment: I never said to be easy @AlexanderMills . But there are sevaral ways to "paste" the emoji. Read expanded answer.

Comment: I can type several unicode characters using the alt key, see my answer

Comment: @AlexanderMills I have read your answer. But having a working `alt-x` sequence is far from universal. Even the linux way of `shift-ctrl-ux` doesn't work in several terminals (like UTerm).

Comment: Check out this answer, what do ya'll think - https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-easily-generate-unicode-characters-with-one-keystroke-on-Linux/answer/Sam-Tanai

Answer (score 3):

systemd uses @ in file paths: `/usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`.  I don't expect any problems for Linux users of your project.  `@` seems pretty safe to me.

I haven't seen any networking command that treats strings containing `@` differently, and that includes `mail`.  The common pattern is actually to use `:`, e.g. `rsync SRC user@host:`.  If you omit the `:`, rsync will create a local file `user@host`, instead of trying to copy to the home directory of `user` on the computer called `host`.

Comment: Just because systemd uses something does not mean it is safe! I would personally stay clear of ANY practice systemd decides to follow, yes, you read that right, ANY.

Comment: @thecarpy it means it's _used_.  Absence of evidence that people have problems with it, suggests that it's not very dangerous on Linux.  + I'm sorry you don't like gcc `__attribute__(cleanup)` but I don't see how that's relevant.

Answer (score -1):

yeah so I am not very hip, but apparently there are quite a few unicode characters you can generate with just the keyboard, using `alt + [x]`.

So instead of an @ sign in a filepath, which requires escaping \@

I will probably use one of these:

∆∑µß

which were generated with the alt key and a character key combined.

And you get tab completion when using these characters too, which is imperative.

If anybody sees a problem with using these types of characters in a filepath please let me know asap :)

Comment: There is a well known problem with filenames in uft8: MSDOS doesn't understand it. And the file system that goes with that: FAT32, also [has problems](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/12048/). In general, this will happen with any filesystem that fail to understand (or even allow) filenames encoded in utf8.

Comment: I only need to support MacOS and Linux..but yeah I need to do more research to ensure it works in general

Comment: [This is a quite good description of the problem in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19507623/8017719).

Comment: And what about the users who don't have an easy way to enter such characters?

Comment: @ilkkachu yes of course that is an important concern - I believe that anyone can generate those characters using the alt key on the keyboard, it's quite easy. For example, ∆ is alt+j, for me.  Is that the same for you?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-easily-generate-unicode-characters-with-one-keystroke-on-Linux/answer/Sam-Tanai